# IE: Padding in horizontal scroll

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am facing IE problem for which I cannot find proper solution.

Comparing Chrome and IE I notice that adding `padding-right` will be excluded from content's width in Chrome and part of width itself in IE.

Is there any proper fix for that, or should I go for browser specific style here?

If explanation is not good enough, please take a look in provided snippet bellow.

```css
.container {
  width: 480px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div><div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please specify (a) which versions of IE you're testing with, and (b) whether IE is rendering the page in standards mode, compatibility mode or quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

> Comparing Chrome and IE I notice that adding padding-right will be excluded from content's width in Chrome and part of width itself in IE.

This is a classic description of the primary difference in rendering when the page is displayed in Quirks mode.

You can fix the rendering mode by making sure your page is valid HTML (that is, it contains all the correct `<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>` tags) and starts with a valid DOCTYPE declaration (there are a number of doctypes you can use but the easiest one is just `<!DOCTYPE html>`).

Make these fixes, and you will find that IE renders your padding exactly the same as Chrome.